# Swift 2 - Change Label Color Working In Simulator But Not On iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicolor

This might be a simple fix but I couldn't find anything about this online. I'm coding in Swift 2 and in the Simulator the text color is changing perfectly. I'm having it change when a certain condition is met. When loading it on my phone the color doesn't change at all. I'm not sure if there is anything else I can do. I tried adding `let` before it but it just gave me more errors.

```
self.TimeCount.textColor = UIColor.redColor();
```

Rest of the code:

```
func Countdown(){
        //Time Left Before Bomb Explodes
        TimerCount -= 1
        if(TimerCount <= 0){
            MainTime.font = UIFont(name: NoDiffuseKit.font.fontName, size: 45)
            self.MainTime.textColor = UIColor.redColor();
            MainTime.text = "No Time"
        }else if(TimerCount == 5){
            self.MainTime.textColor = UIColor.redColor();
            MainTime.text = "5"
        }else{
            MainTime.text = "\(TimerCount)"
            Main = TimerCount
        }
        //Time Left To Diffuse With A Kit
        Kit = Main - 5
        if(Kit <= 0){
            DiffuseKit.font = UIFont(name: DiffuseKit.font.fontName, size: 15)
            self.DiffuseKit.textColor = UIColor.redColor();
            DiffuseKit.text = "No Time"
        }else if(Kit == 5){
            self.DiffuseKit.textColor = UIColor.redColor();
            DiffuseKit.text = "5"
        }else{
            DiffuseKit.text = "\(Kit)"
        }
        //Time Left To Diffuse Without A Kit
        NoKit = Main - 10
        if(NoKit <= 0){
            NoDiffuseKit.font = UIFont(name: NoDiffuseKit.font.fontName, size: 15)
            self.NoDiffuseKit.textColor = UIColor.redColor();
            NoDiffuseKit.text = "No Time"
        }else if(NoKit == 5){
            self.NoDiffuseKit.textColor = UIColor.redColor();
            NoDiffuseKit.text = "5"
        }else{
            NoDiffuseKit.text = "\(NoKit)"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func ToggleButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        //If The Button Is At Its Default at 45 Seconds & Not Running
        if(Toggle == false){
            if TimerRunning == false{
                Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Countdown"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                TimerRunning = true;
                Toggle = true;
            }
        //If Timer is Running & Needs To Be Stopped
        }else if (Toggle == true){
            if TimerRunning == true{
                Timer.invalidate()
                TimerRunning = false
                TimerCount = 45;
                MainTime.text = "45"
                DiffuseKit.text = "40"
                NoDiffuseKit.text = "35"
                Toggle = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that "certain condition" is met on your phone as well?

Comment: The condition is a check of the countdown timer.

Comment: Post more code so we can see the condition etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look to see if the timer callback is being run in the main thread; if not use `dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue(), <YOUR CODE IN BLOCK>)`

The issue is that anything that updates the UI must be run from the main thread.

Also check to make sure the font name you have is correct; the device is case sensitive but the default Mac (thus simulator) file system is not.

Comment: What code do I insert where it says `<YOUR CODE IN BLCOK>`. Everything in my ViewController.swift file? I moved my whole Countdown function into it and it gives me an `Expected Declaration` error.